# SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out | pgAdmin 4, Postgres

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am facing constant time-outs if I leave my session idle for more than 60 seconds or so and then try to query.

pgAdmin4, Version 5.7 (4280.88)
PostgreSQL 13.4

> ERROR: SSL SYSCALL error: Operation timed out

Both of these are set to 0.

```
SHOW statement_timeout;
SHOW idle_in_transaction_session_timeout;
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

I have to re-connect the session to get it to work, and this way all the temp tables are lost.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a misconfigured network component that drops the connection when it is idle.

The typical way to combat that is to configure TCP keepalive, either on the operating system or on the PostgreSQL server using the `tcp_keepalives_idle` parameter or with the libpq client connection parameter `keepalives_idle` (although I think that you cannot use connection strings with pgAdmin).

Comment: `show tcp_keepalives_idle` gives a value of 240 on pgadmin. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Sure. Edit `postgresql.conf` on the database server or use `ALTER SYSTEM`. Don't forget to reload the server.

Comment: I dont have the super user rights. `ERROR:  must be superuser to execute ALTER SYSTEM command` Is there no solution to change this locally on my pgadmin?
Because this problem only started after I did a fresh install of pgadmin(latest version)

Comment: You will have to ask the database administrator to change the parameter.